# Devise Token Auth - Use POST to sign in. GET is not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, omniauth

I installed devise token auth and ng-token-auth in my ruby/angularjs project and I was trying out authentication via facebook/google. Unsuccess, I get the next error =>

```
{"errors":["Use POST /sign_in to sign in. GET is not supported."]}
```

My server log shows:

```
Started GET "/omniauth/facebook/callback?code=AQCJG_Oz26o9PADnpL_arsnTN5E38EFikWZDXiQHXEYki1wPNt4dkqpXHE_8SrbGbweh29VmGQleegapuvVf8jOQmVhtz1prLy7GLRr40i07O24M4iNY8WQFVqKD3TIRmqgsj-puaP61KzUdpR0LHw_yeeguX38FDV_4KjHAHa0D4OLipA6ofd78eXQoEhvdkvtFnguuJGfKt0N6eEj9m1h185F2jkZqaZAwh6lM_VQTnDiwOWy10IHYA62yXWk0MJv28AhhoszC-R7tdFvxAEwn6C7IsMhxY7aBZp6VJwegJyQBBydwXb5QpMnOi4oNLSvi6oKARQkQ5i8Mku5tcqTA&state=8bf6fcfb4dedcf2f22fa3bef875d0e91b63ac0c9b7a8f8a6" for ::1 at 2017-01-29 12:38:34 -0300
Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"AQCJG_Oz26o9PADnpL_arsnTN5E38EFikWZDXiQHXEYki1wPNt4dkqpXHE_8SrbGbweh29VmGQleegapuvVf8jOQmVhtz1prLy7GLRr40i07O24M4iNY8WQFVqKD3TIRmqgsj-puaP61KzUdpR0LHw_yeeguX38FDV_4KjHAHa0D4OLipA6ofd78eXQoEhvdkvtFnguuJGfKt0N6eEj9m1h185F2jkZqaZAwh6lM_VQTnDiwOWy10IHYA62yXWk0MJv28AhhoszC-R7tdFvxAEwn6C7IsMhxY7aBZp6VJwegJyQBBydwXb5QpMnOi4oNLSvi6oKARQkQ5i8Mku5tcqTA", "state"=>"8bf6fcfb4dedcf2f22fa3bef875d0e91b63ac0c9b7a8f8a6"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

What I understand is that my app is starting a Get method instead of POST, but how can I change that?

I've been reading other post about this but no one gives an answer.

My routes:

```
     user_facebook_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /omniauth/facebook(.:format)               omniauth_callbacks#passthru
      user_facebook_omniauth_callback GET|POST /omniauth/facebook/callback(.:format)      omniauth_callbacks#facebook
user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /omniauth/google_oauth2(.:format)          omniauth_callbacks#passthru
 user_google_oauth2_omniauth_callback GET|POST /omniauth/google_oauth2/callback(
```

Thank you.

EDIT: I add my client side code:

HTML (a simple link to a angular function)

```
 <a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-social btn-facebook social-butt" ng-click="facebooksignup()"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Regístrate con Facebook!</a>
```

My angularjs controller:

```
$scope.facebooksignup = function(){
         $auth.authenticate('facebook')
        .then(function(resp) {
          // handle success
        })
        .catch(function(resp) {
          // handle errors
        });
```

And my module configuration:

```
app.config(function($authProvider) {
       $authProvider.configure({
           apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1',
           validateOnPageLoad: false,
           authProviderPaths: {
              facebook: '/auth/facebook',
              google:   '/auth/google'
          }
       });
   });
```

Comment: Do you have a form or something?

Comment: I've just edited my post adding my client side code. I'm using ng-token-auth basically.